# How to read nested table

Tags: lua, nested, lua-table

I am new to lua and want to learn about nested table

This is what I have been trying:

```
t = {};
t[1] = 22, {1, 22, 3};
t[2] = 44, {4, 5, 6}; 
t[3] = 66, {4, 5, 6};

for k, v in ipairs(t) do 
print(k,v) 
end
```

This does not work for me. 
   This is the result I want:
        Example:

```
    1 2 5
   2 5 66
   3 6 33
    4 2 1
    5 4 12
   6 4 3
    7 2 44
    8 3 1
    9 2 44
   10 3 99


How do I read a nested table like this and
how do I table.insert in the right column?
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the misunderstanding lies in this code:

`t[1] = 22, {1, 22, 3}`

The 2nd value, the one after the comma, `{1, 22, 3}` is being assigned to nothing, it is dropped in the ether.

Perhaps what you meant was a table of tables:

`t[1] = {22, {1, 22, 3}}`

This would create an entry at [1] in `t` that is itself..a table

`t[1][1] == 22
t[1][2] == {1, 22, 3}`

Then to iterate this setup you could use:

`local t = {}
t[1] = {22, {1, 22, 3}}
t[2] = {44, {4, 5, 6}}
t[3] = {66, {4, 5, 6}}
for _,entry in ipairs(t) do
  local key = entry[1]
  io.write(key .. ' ')
  for _,value in ipairs(entry[2]) do
    io.write(value .. ' ')
  end
  io.write('\n')
end`

But to be honest, I'm not sure what you're asking as your "expected output" is significantly different than your sample data set.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer.  I think i mean that its enough with:                              t[1] = {22, 3}
t[2] = {44, 6}
t[3] = {66, 63} How to iterate over this table in the simplest possibly way?

Answer (score 0):

Replying to Qualmos' comment in payo's answer:

```
local t = {}
t[1] = {22,3}
t[2] = {44,6}
t[3] = {66,63}

for _,v in pairs(table) do
   print(_,v[1],v[2])
end
```

Would print something like this:

```
1,22,3
2,44,6
3,66,63
```

Btw, you can make the table look like this:

```
local t = {
    {22,3};
    {44,6};
    {66,63};
}
```